# Trigger azure functions based on deviceids

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have two devices registered in IoT Hub. say device1 and device2. I have two azure functions say azurefunction1 and azurefunction2.

When a message is sent to Iot Hub with device1 I want azurefunction1 to get triggered but not azurefunction2. 
Similarly When a message is sent to Iot Hub with device2 I want azurefunction2 to get triggered but not azurefunction1.

I tried using consumer groups but both azure functions are getting triggered.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly possible. Events from both devices go to the same Event Hub, and Event Hub is the level of granularity for Functions trigger.

Consumer groups are for independent consumers, which *both* will get *all* events.

I would suggest you having a single Function to receive events from all devices. This Function could then route the request based on Device ID to other Functions if needed, e.g. via HTTP calls or via separate Storage Queues.

Comment: There is [IoT Hub routing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-iot-hub-message-routing-enhances-device-telemetry-and-optimizes-iot-infrastructure-resources/) which with _some_ convincing could use multiple Service Bus queues to do that, however i agree with you and it's probably a terrible idea to go that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use IoT Hub routing. You can route events to different IoT Hub endpoints based in the deviceid. You can then have azurefunction1 connected to the endpoint for device1, and azurefunction2 connected to the endpoint for device2.

The [Routing Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing) tutorial describes how to configure and use routing.

Comment: There is a limit 10 custom endpoints in the IoT Hub, so with an IoT Hub Routes we can route max 11 devices and additional cost is 10 x US$21.90 per month. Btw. In the case of two devices, we need only one more Event Hub custom endpoint.

Comment: In addition, I agree with a Mikhail's suggestion for routing a telemetry messages in the Function. Btw. this Function can be also implemented as a publisher for custom topic of the Event Grid.